# radios.length issue - java script

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Perhaps it is very basic, but I have some issue with the radios.length property. I have some input like so :

```
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="test1" checked='checked'/><br />
<input type="radio" name="name2" value="test2" checked='checked'/><br />
```

When I alert the radios.length property, I always have 0 as an answer. Could someone explain why ?

Comment: Where are you getting `radios` from? Is this a variable set somewhere else? Or are you just doing raw javascript?

Comment: I am trying to use raw javascript

Comment: There is no `radios` variable in raw javascript. You need to query the DOM for the list of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**radios.length** is not a valid property in the DOM.. 
You need to find those(which are input in this case) and then use the length property on it ..

```
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input") ;

alert(radios.length) // this will alert the correct value
```

**UPDATE**

To Select only the Radio buttons you can do this

```
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input") ;
var checkBoxes = [];

for(​var i =0, len = radios.length; i< len;i++){
    if(radios[i].type === 'radio'){
        checkBoxes.push(radios[i]);
    }
};

console.log(checkBoxes)​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4jmUb/)**

Also if you are using jQuery do not forget to encase your script in **DOM Ready** handler

**jQuery**

```
$('#radio1').attr('type') // Need to use the .attr() method
```

**[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4jmUb/1/)**

Comment: But this is only true, if there are no other input elements, like text fields, password fields or submit buttons.

Comment: Yes it worked but if I make an alert(inputs[0].type), where I named inputs[0] to refer to the first input, I have again a 0 displayed. Does it mean anything to you ?

Comment: What is inputs here ?? .. If inputs means the input element then without first selecting them with tag names you cannot do that

Comment: here inputs is an array gathering all the input-entry of the page. Btw, I ran <script type="text/javascript">alert($('#id').type);</script>, where $id is the id of the input, and I get an alert message telling me it is undefined

Comment: If you are using jQuery then you are supposed to use $('#id').attr('type')  .. .type is not a valid method of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

`radios` is not a valid object in the browser. You need to search the DOM for the `inputs`.

Using jQuery:

```
$("input[type=radio]").length
```

would give you `2`

In raw javascript, you could do something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

But this would give you ALL `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use document.querySelectorAll(). It allows to retrieve elements by css selector and is supported by all major browsers, including IE >= 8.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fNhmr/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll